# Fixed To Top Menu in Yii Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I need a simple clarification on this, I have a menu. Whenever I scroll Down I need this menu to appear at the side of my page. Please help me doing this.

View:

```
<div id="fl_menu">
    <div class="label">MENU</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">An menu item</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">A long menu item</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">Item 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">Another one</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">A really, really long menu item</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">Menu item 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">And one more</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu_item">A tiny</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
<script>  


//STICKY NAV
$(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = $('#fl_menu').offset().top - parseFloat($('#fl_menu').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 100));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#fl_menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#fl_menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This has absolutely nothing to do with Yii. Anyway you are looking for this
http://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-affix/